# How to know the value of id when the incoming request ends with 404?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

For illustration purpose, let me make a simple example as follows.

#### Review.cshtml.cs:

```
public class ReviewModel : PageModel
{
    public void OnGet(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
            ViewData["X"] = "null";
        else
            ViewData["X"] = id;
    }
}
```

#### Review.cshtml:

```
@page 

@model ReviewModel

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    X = @ViewData["X"]
</body>
</html>
```

When I navigate to

- `localhost/Review/1` --------------- 404.
- `localhost/Review/xyz` --------------- 404.
- `localhost/Review/` --------------- `X=null`.
- `localhost/Review?id=1` --------------- `X=1`.
- `localhost/Review?id=` --------------- `X=null`.
- `localhost/Review?id=xyz` --------------- `X=null`.

I attempted to use Visual Studio Debugger to figure out the value of `id` when 404 pages are thrown but I cannot step into.

How to know the value of id when the incoming request ends with 404?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it has to do with routing, you should be able to make your own route with something like this in your Startup.cs:

```
options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/Review", "Review/{id?}");
```

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/razor-pages/razor-pages-convention-features

Comment: @ArtificialStupidity You should be able to debug your code now instead of getting an 404. But you have to change the type from int? to string if you want to catch the value that is anything other than an int

Comment: @ArtificialStupidity Okay, maybe I'm not getting your question correctly?
You get 404 and because of that you dont get the value of id. Correct?

Comment: It uses naming conventions, and Review/1 is not following the convention, thats why you get 404.